# Index - reference to subsections

Tags: indexing

When indexing I don't want the pagenumber to be the reference, but rather the section / subsection of the entry. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please add a MWE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done by redefining `\@wrindex` to write the index entry immediately and with the section/subsection number instead of the page number.

Since the subsection number is usually separated by a dot from the section number, the makeindex variable `page_compositor` is set to a dot via a job name specific style file. Makeindex will automatically look for `<jobname>.mst` and use it as style file if it exists.

Complete example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
page_compositor "."
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
    \set@display@protect
    \immediate\write\@indexfile{%
      \protect\indexentry{#1}{%
        \ifnum\value{subsection}=0 %
          \thesection
        \else
          \thesubsection
        \fi
      }%
    }%  
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
  \index{first}
  \index{section}
\subsection{First subsection}
  \index{first}
  \index{subsection}
\section{Second section}
  \index{second}
  \index{section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
  \index{subsection}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Another section}
  \index{section}
\subsection{Last subsection}
  \index{subsection}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### With level "chapter"

The following example also uses level "chapter" as requested in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185236/index-reference-to-subsections/185268?noredirect=1#comment941796_185268):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
page_compositor "."
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
    \set@display@protect
    \immediate\write\@indexfile{%
      \protect\indexentry{#1}{%
        \ifnum\value{section}=0 %
          \thechapter
        \else
          \ifnum\value{subsection}=0 %
            \thesection
          \else
            \thesubsection
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
  \index{first}
  \index{chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
  \index{second}
  \index{chapter}
\section{First section}
  \index{first}
  \index{section}
\subsection{First subsection}
  \index{first}
  \index{subsection}
\section{Second section}
  \index{second}
  \index{section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
  \index{second}
  \index{subsection}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Another section}
  \index{section}
\subsection{Last subsection}
  \index{subsection}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: And how could I use this code for indexing not only the section and subsection but also the chapter?

Comment: @Aradnix See updated answer.