# Index - reference to subsections with hyperlink to page

Tags: cross-referencing, makeindex

I'm looking to create an index with references to subsections (and an even more complex numbering scheme).

So far I was able to do that quite nicely using the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185236/index-reference-to-subsections). However I would like to have a hyperref link to the page on the *section.subsection.subsusection.etc* number. Any way I could do that?

Comment: Please clarify your objectives. The title and the first paragraph currently mention subsections, while the second paragraph seems to point to subsubsections. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your way of numbering index-entries makes index-entries to only occur under a numbered sectioning header a requirement. (How to number an index-entry under a starred/unnumbered section—e.g., `\section*{foo} bar\index{bar}...` ?)

Another requirement will be that sectioning-headers are numbered according to the following pattern: Each part of the number is formatted

- either in lowercase roman,
- or in numeric or arabic,
- or in lowercase alphabetic,
- or in uppercase roman,
- or in uppercase alphabetic.

All parts of a number are separated from each other by a special string which can be specified in *makeindex* as `page_compositor`.

In *makeindex* you can—afaik—specify only one `page_compositor`-string.

In case you have such composed section-numbering where parts of the section number have different formats, e.g., `IV.3.2` (`.` must be the `page_compositor`), you need to also specify the `page_precedence` for sorting the numbers.

Also be aware that things like `\part` provide roman numerals. In case `\part` hasn't been used yet, the value of `\c@part` will be 0 which is not a positive number while `\romannumeral` will silently not deliver any token at all in case the number in question is not positive...

Besides sectioning-numbers, you also need to provide info about names of anchors/targets for hyperlinking.

As the `\index`-macro does read its argument in a way where it cannot be expanded further, this needs to be done by patching that part of the mechanism that does write index-entries to .idx-files, i.e., by `\@wrindex`.

Forming a hyperlink from a sectioning-number means formatting that sectioning-number. With index-entries the mechanism for formatting them is the `|⟨name of formatting-command⟩`-thingie.

As we have to use this thingie within `\@wrindex`, it cannot be used within the argument of the `\index`-macro any more.

Things like `|see` and `|seealso` might be broken.

In order to get such things to work, you'd need either to patch the `\index`-macro itself so that it reads its argument in a way where expansion-trickery is still possible, or to patch `\@wrindex` so that it sophistically parses its argument and automatically inserts the things needed for creating hyperlinks and hypertargets/anchors.

The latter would probably by the better approach although implementing the parsing-routine might turn out a tricky and time-consuming job: You'd not be done by simply searching for characters `!`, `|` and `@` because these can also occur preceded by `"` which means that they are to be treated as ordinary characters by *makeindex*. (Perhaps some trickery could be applied for first replacing all occurrences of `!`/`|`/`@`preceded by `"` by tokens of same character-code but of different category code... )

Besides this, there would be a requirement to have each `\index`-entry referenced by thingies like `|see` and `|seealso` turned into a `\hypertarget` that can be linked via `\hyperlink` from the referencing item. The macros `\see` and `\seealso` would require patching in order to create `hyperlink`s to those `hypertarget`s.

Leaving all those problems aside, the following code might provide some kind of starting point for you:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
page_compositor "."
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand\My@definewritesection[1]{%
  \My@@definewritesection{#1}{}{}%
}%
\newcommand\My@@definewritesection[3]{%
   \My@definewritesectionloop{#1}#1{.}\relax{#2}{#3}%
}%
\newcommand\My@definewritesectionloop{}
\def\My@definewritesectionloop#1#2#3\relax#4#5{%
  \ifx\relax#3\relax
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \expandafter\My@@definewritesection
    \expandafter{\@gobble#1}{{#2}#4}{{#1}#5}%
  }{%
    \My@definewritesectionloopB
       {\My@Writeifdefinedloop{}#4\relax}#4{.}\relax#5{.}\relax
    \My@definewritehypersectionloopB
       {\My@Writeifdefinedloop{H}#4\relax}#4{.}\relax#5{.}\relax
  }%
}%
\newcommand\My@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\My@definewritesectionloopB{}%
\long\def\My@definewritesectionloopB#1#2#3\relax#4#5\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#3#5\relax
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            \My@definewritesectionloopB
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            {%
    \expandafter\My@Exchange
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter{%
    \csname the#2\endcsname}}{\My@InCaseOneOfIsZero{#4}{#1}}%
    }#3\relax#5\relax
  }{%
    \newcommand\My@writesection{#1}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\My@definewritehypersectionloopB{}%
\long\def\My@definewritehypersectionloopB#1#2#3\relax#4#5\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#3#5\relax
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            \My@definewritehypersectionloopB
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter           {%
    \expandafter\My@Exchange
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter{%
    \romannumeral
      \expandafter\My@Exchange
      \expandafter{%
      \csname theH#2\endcsname}{0 #2.}}}{\My@InCaseOneOfIsZero{#4}{#1}}%
    }#3\relax#5\relax
  }{%
    \newcommand\My@writehypersection{#1}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\My@InCaseOneOfIsZero[1]{%
  \My@IsZeroLoop{\@secondoftwo}#1\relax
}%
\newcommand\My@IsZeroLoop[2]{%
  \ifx\relax#2\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
  {%
    \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@secondoftwo}{%
      \ifnum\the\csname c@#2\endcsname=0 %
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
    }%
    {\My@IsZeroLoop{\@firstoftwo}}%
    {\My@IsZeroLoop{#1}}%
  }{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\My@gobbletorelax{}%
\long\def\My@gobbletorelax#1\relax{}
\newcommand\My@Writeifdefinedloop[2]{%
  \ifx\relax#2\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  {%
    \@ifundefined{the#1#2}{%
      \@ifundefined{the#2}%
                   {\My@Writeifdefinedloop{#1}}%
                   {\csname the#2\expandafter\endcsname\My@gobbletorelax}%
    }{\csname the#1#2\expandafter\endcsname\My@gobbletorelax}%
  }%
}%

% This will define \My@writesection  and
% \My@writehypersection.
%
% \My@writesection will write the \the<countername>-printing
% of the value of that sectioning counter which belongs to the 
% lowest sectioning-level where both the counter itself and 
% counters of all superordinate sectioning levels do not have 
% the value 0.
% (In case no such counter exists, e.g., as there is no
% sectioning heading at all before the `\index`-entry in question,
% the \the<countername>-printing of the value of the counter 
% belonging to the most superordinate existing sectioning level 
% will be used. That value should be zero. In that case
% \My@writehypersection, see below, will attempt to create an
% anchor-name for that counter. The likelihood is high that
% in this case an anchor of the created name does not exist
% which means that in this case you will get warning-messages
% and .log-file-entries about non existing destinations that
% were replaced by fixed ones.
% There are scenarios involving \romannumeral, where the 
% \the<countername>-printing of counters of value 0 doesn't yield
% any token at all.)
%
% \My@writehypersection will attempt to create the name
% of the corresponding anchor/hypertarget produced by
% `\refstepcouter` by concatenating the name of that counter, a dot
% and \theH<countername>.
%
\My@definewritesection{%
  {subsubsubparagraph}%
  {subsubparagraph}%
  {subparagraph}%
  {paragraph}%
  {subsubsection}%
  {subsection}%
  {section}%
  {chapter}%
  % If a sectioning level/a sectioning-counter occurring in this 
  % list is undefined, that doesn't matter. E.g., there are
  % documentclasses where \chapter and the chapter-counter aren't
  % defined at all...
  %
  % But distinguish the case of a sectioning level being undefined 
  % from the case of a sectioning-level being defined but unused while
  % sectioning headings of subordinate levels are used!!!
  % The latter case is not good practice but there are people who
  % do it anyway.
  %
  % Don't include the part-counter into the hierarchy of
  % sectioning counters.
  %
  % Although \part is a means for dividing a work into
  % portions, it is not an element of that sectioning hierarchy 
  % which is formed by section headings. 
  % Therefore \part does not reset any other counters that
  % belong to the hierarchy of sectioning headings.
  % E.g., \part does not reset the chapter-counter.
  %
  % Besides this: If part is not used, it has the value 0. 
  % If you---while not using \part---consider the part
  % counter an element of the set of those counters that belong 
  % to the hierarchy of sectioning headings, then no
  % sectioning-counter in the hierarchy will not have
  % a superordinate sectioning counter of value 0...
  %
  % Besides this, parts are numbered in roman numerals
  % while \romannumeral0 yields no tokens at all...
}%

\renewcommand*\@wrindex[1]{%
    \set@display@protect
    \immediate\write\@indexfile{%
      \protect\indexentry{#1\string|hyperlink{\My@writehypersection}}%
                         {\My@writesection}%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
  \index{first} 
  \index{chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
  \index{second}
  \index{chapter}
\section{First section}
  \index{first}
  \index{section}
\subsection{First subsection}
  \index{first}
  \index{subsection}
\section{Second section}
  \index{second}
  \index{section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
  \index{second}
  \index{subsection}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Another section}
  \index{section}
\subsection{Last subsection}
  \index{subsection}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer! Your starting point will prove very useful.